# Ruby on Rails audio not playing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm having trouble playing an mp3 file all the way through. I'm using the `paperclip` gem.

Here's my `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= image_tag @play.image.url(:medium) %>


<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @play.description %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= audio_tag @play.audio, :type => "audio/mp3", :controls => true %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_play_path(@play) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', plays_path %>
```

Everything is showing up in the show view, but once I hit the play button to listen to the audio file, it only plays for about 3 sec's and then it stops and goes back to the beginning.  The audio track displays the length of the song in the show view, which is 3 min in length.

Anyone know what the issue could be?? Thanks!

Comment: Are you local?  Are you using webrick?

Comment: Yea, I'm local and using webrick

Comment: try unicorn instead.  webrick has some issues that can be problematic.  `gem unicorn` // `bundle`  // `unicorn -p 3000` -- you might find that files you uploaded with webrick don't play correctly - try uploading a new one and then see if it streams just fine